# Unexpected token ':' when using supervisor with laravel queue

Tags: laravel, supervisord

I'm trying to set up supervisor 4.2.1 to monitor my queues. I am on Mac OS X Big Sur and running laravel 6.20 with a database queue.

I am getting an error stating **unexpected ":"** when trying to read my .conf file.

I have:

1. Placed a file /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf that contains the following (Note the path to artisan is fake):

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /path/to/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3 --timeout=3600
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/logs/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

After installing this, I have tried to load it with the supervisor, using both its CLI and the supervisorctl process, and I get the following error. I believe this is how the conf file should be formatted:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Program node /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf exited with code 1
```

Seems like a simple error but I'm not sure why I'm getting it. I used the sample laravel-worker.conf file provided by Laravel's Documentation and various github repos.

It is not even noticing that the queue exists, as it can't read my conf file. What should I change?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you're running Supervisord version 4.2.1?
I just tested the configuration file you pasted and it works fine for me (I'm on 4.1.0)

Comment: hm checking now. I think it is 4.2.0_1, but I'm going to try 4.1.0

Comment: Actually, I can't seem to find 4.2.0_1 because it is not in the list of versions in brew. So I think I'm stuck running 4.2.0_1. Yeah I'm not sure what's causing this issue. It is mid-priority as now I'm just relying on manually starting queues. I'm not sure if it's a me thing or a python 3.9 thing, or I'm missing a config somewhere in my app. When you run supervisorctl start, the queues don't need to already be started right? It just runs them in the background?

Comment: Yeah, supervisor should start them by itself.  Maybe you found a bug - you could try and file an issue at https://github.com/supervisor/supervisor/issues

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Sure, will do